# Можно ли использовать assetManager.list() в многопотоке?

Tags: многопоточность, android-assets

Значит есть проблема - мне нужно из ассетов прочесть и превратить в объекты множество json файлов которые распределены по папкам. Для ускорения работы я использую 2 потока которые запускаю через CompletableFuture.runAsync(). Каждому потоку даю свой список папок которые нужно обработать.

И у меня проблема - количество созданных объектов в итоге получается разным, но если все папки читать в одном потоке то все нормально. Как я подозреваю то проблема или в многопоточном доступе к assetManager.list() или в Gson.fromJson() или в еще чем-то.

И как мне быть? Синхронизация доступа к assetManager.list() сведет почти в 0 все преимущества многопоточности так же как и  Gson.fromJson(). Или многопоток и ассеты в Андроиде невозможны?